# Verificar se JSONObject possui determinada chave

Tags: java, json

`this.token()` é uma `String` do tipo `{"erro" : "Valor do erro"}`.

Mas também, em caso de sucesso pode ser:  `{"token" : "Valor do token"}`

Meu objetivo com o código abaixo é descobrir se o primeiro índice desse `JSONObject` a ser criado será `"erro"` ou `"token"` e estou tentando assim, mas parece que está testando se o valor para o índice `"erro"` é nulo e não se o próprio índice erro existe ou não.

```
JSONObject token = new JSONObject(this.token());

if (token.get("erro").equals(null))
    this.resposta.setText(token.getString("token"));
else
    this.resposta.setText(token.getString("erro"));
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Segundo a documentação de `JSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#get(java.lang.String)),  o método `get` lança uma exceção ([`JSONException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONException.html)) caso a chave não exista. E pelo que entendi, ou o JSON tem a chave `"erro"`, ou tem a chave `"token"`, então se não tiver a chave `"erro"` e você tentar acessá-la com `get`, será lançada uma exceção.

Você *até poderia* usar um `try`/`catch` para capturar a exceção e saber se a chave existe ou não, mas para testar se uma chave existe, você pode simplesmente usar o [método `has`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)), que retorna `true` ou `false` (caso a chave exista ou não):

```
JSONObject token = new JSONObject(this.token());

if (token.has("erro")) // tem erro
    this.resposta.setText(token.getString("erro"));
else // não tem erro, então pela sua descrição, deve ter a chave token
    this.resposta.setText(token.getString("token"));
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo! Muito, mas muito obrigado!